# Filter database based on max and min that varies each year

Tags: r, filter, group-by, max, min

I have a database that looks like this:

```
    Year ID Date Occupy
    2010 1  10   Yes
    2010 2  11   No
    2010 3  12   Yes
    2010 4  9    No
    2010 5  15   No
    2011 7  7    Yes
    2011 8  9    Yes
    2011 9  10   Yes
    2011 11 12   No
```

I am trying to create a code that first checks which dates are the first and last ones to be occupied (here date is the day of the month) each year. In 2010, these dates should be 10 and 12,and in 2011, 7 and 10. Then the code should filter out those rows with dates smaller or bigger than these first and last occupied dates.

The outcome should be:

```
    Year ID Date Occupy
    2010 1  10   Yes
    2010 2  11   No
    2010 3  12   Yes
    2011 7  7    Yes
    2011 8  9    Yes
    2011 9  10   Yes
```

I tried to do these two steps in two separate parts using:

```
    lapply(function(x) c(min(x), max(x)))
```

and then grouping and filtering with lubridate, but everything crashes or does not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you prefer `dplyr` syntax:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- tribble(
        ~Year, ~ID, ~Date, ~Occupy,
         2010,   1,    10,   "Yes",
         2010,   2,    11,    "No",
         2010,   3,    12,   "Yes",
         2010,   4,     9,    "No",
         2010,   5,    15,    "No",
         2011,   7,     7,   "Yes",
         2011,   8,     9,   "Yes",
         2011,   9,    10,   "Yes",
         2011,  11,    12,    "No"
        )

df |> 
  mutate(
    min_occupied = min(Date[Occupy == "Yes"]),
    max_occupied = max(Date[Occupy == "Yes"]),
    .by = Year
  ) |> 
  filter(between(Date, min_occupied, max_occupied))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 6
#>    Year    ID  Date Occupy min_occupied max_occupied
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>         <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1  2010     1    10 Yes              10           12
#> 2  2010     2    11 No               10           12
#> 3  2010     3    12 Yes              10           12
#> 4  2011     7     7 Yes               7           10
#> 5  2011     8     9 Yes               7           10
#> 6  2011     9    10 Yes               7           10
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hi @dufei, thanks for your suggestion. However, for some reason this code doesn´t work: I copied and pasted your exact same code (didn´t change a coma), and got a different result. It produced a tibble with the same min and max dates for both years (7 and 12), and thus only removed the last row of year 2010 (with date=15). Could this be a package/R version problem?

Comment: I updated my Rstudio and dplyr, and still had issues. Then I changed the ".by" for "group_by", and "|>" for "%>%". Now your whole code runs ok with the reprex. However, when I run your whole code with my data R throws an error and says that 

"Caused by error in `between()`: ! `left` must be length 1"

Actually, the R documentation on the between() function mentions that left and right "must be scalars". So I am confused about why is this code running with the reprex but not with my actual data. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Teresa, have you made sure that the `between()` you are using is coming from the package `dplyr`? `dplyr::between()` does accept vectors as boundary values. I would also suggest you update your R installation (I'm using version 4.3.1) to get rid of the errors relating to `|>` etc. first. You can check your version of R using`R.Version()`. Hope this helps!

Comment: Fantastic! after updating R and specifying dplyr::between the code works! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

a one-liner `data.table` approach (probably not the most elegant way, but I could not think of another approach at the end of the day ;-) )

```
library(data.table)
mydata <- fread("    Year ID Date Occupy
                 2010 1  10   Yes
                 2010 2  11   No
                 2010 3  12   Yes
                 2010 4  9    No
                 2010 5  15   No
                 2011 7  7    Yes
                 2011 8  9    Yes
                 2011 9  10   Yes
                 2011 11 12   No")

# or setDT(mydata)
mydata[mydata[Occupy == "Yes", .(min = min(Date), max = max(Date)), Year], 
   .(Year = x.Year, ID = x.ID, Date = x.Date, Occupy = x.Occupy), 
   on = .(Year, Date >= min, Date <= max)]

#    Year ID Date Occupy
# 1: 2010  1   10    Yes
# 2: 2010  2   11     No
# 3: 2010  3   12    Yes
# 4: 2011  7    7    Yes
# 5: 2011  8    9    Yes
# 6: 2011  9   10    Yes
```

other approach, same result, shorter code

```
mydata[ID %in% mydata[mydata[Occupy == "Yes", .(min = min(Date), max = max(Date)), Year], 
                      ID, on = .(Year, Date >= min, Date <= max)], ]
```

Comment: I like the logic - another variation to avoid the `x.variable` bits - `dat[dat[dat[Occupy=="Yes", .(mnd=min(Date), mxd=max(Date)), by=Year], on=.(Year,Date>=mnd,Date<=mxd), which=TRUE]]`

Answer (score 0):

An uncommon approach using easy-to-read `{dplyr}` syntax:

```
library(dplyr)
data1 <- 
  data |>
  filter(Occupy == "No") |>
  mutate(minD = NA, 
         maxD = NA)
data2 <- 
  data |>
  filter(Occupy == "Yes") |>
  mutate(minD = min(Date), 
         maxD = max(Date), .by = Year)

rbind(data1, data2) |>
  mutate(
    flag = ifelse(
      Occupy == "No" & Date %in% c(min(minD, na.rm = TRUE):max(maxD, na.rm = TRUE)),
      1L, 0L), .by = Year) |>
  filter(Occupy == "Yes" | flag == 1L) |>
  group_by(Year, Date) |>
  arrange(Date, .by_group = TRUE) |>
  select(-c(minD, maxD, flag))
```

which gives

```
#> # A tibble: 6 × 4
#> # Groups:   Year, Date [6]
#>    Year    ID  Date Occupy
#>   <int> <int> <int> <chr> 
#> 1  2010     1    10 Yes   
#> 2  2010     2    11 No    
#> 3  2010     3    12 Yes   
#> 4  2011     7     7 Yes   
#> 5  2011     8     9 Yes   
#> 6  2011     9    10 Yes
```

An R-base version using `ave()` and `by()`.

```
# (1) 
data <- within(data, {
  # I think ave's FUN argument does not accept more than one function 
  minD <- ave(Date, list(Year, Occupy), FUN = min)
  maxD <- ave(Date, list(Year, Occupy), FUN = max)
  }) 
# (2)
data[data$Occupy == "No", c("minD", "maxD")] <- NA 
# (3)
by(data,
   INDICES = data$Year, 
   FUN = \(x) {
       x$flag <- ifelse(x$Occupy == "No" & x$Date 
                        %in% c(min(x$minD, na.rm = TRUE):max(x$maxD, na.rm = TRUE)), 
                        1L, 0L)
       return(x)}) |>
  `names<-`(NULL) |>
  { \(x) do.call("rbind", x) }() |>
  { \(x) x[x$Occupy == "Yes" | x$flag == 1L, 1L:4L] }()
```

Would be interesting to know how to pipe (1), (2), and (3) together.